# Adding Attributed Text on X axis Label in bar graph using iOS charts

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I am trying to implement bar graph using iOS charts library. https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts. I want to add J 2018 as x-axis label where "J" is bigger font and 2018 is in lower font using iOS charts in bar graph. Any one can help me into it. I have added image of expected bar graph x axis.

[I want some thing like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zH4N0.png)